# How do I make every class generated by Struct.new to have a class method?

Tags: ruby

My problem is, I have a bunch of classes that extend Struct.new. And now I need add a common class method to all of them.
If Struct was a 'normal' superclass, I would be able to define a class method on it and then every subclass would also have that method.

Given, that it is not, how do I replicate this behaviour?
For example,

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:foo); end
Foo.respond_to?(:perform) #=> true
class Bar < Struct.new(:bar); end
Bar.respond_to?(:perform) #=> true
```

Comment: Define it in a module and include to your subclasses.

Comment: This was my initial approach, but it is error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you define a method on Struct?

```
def Struct.perform
end

class Foo < Struct.new(:foo); end
Foo.respond_to?(:perform) #=> true
class Bar < Struct.new(:bar); end
Bar.respond_to?(:perform) #=> true
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks! But how is this different from ```class Struct; def perform; end; end``` ?

Comment: That would add an instance method

Comment: Oops, i meant ```class Struct; def self.perform; end; end```

Comment: As far as the method itself goes, basically the same. There are some differences regarding constant lookup since in the latter case the lexical scope is the Struct class whereas in the former it's the top level

Comment: Yeah, this was a stupid question. I dont know what happened but I can swear the first time I tried the latter case it did not work. Thanks for taking the time and answering.